How to create complex conditions with Webform?
On Drupal 10.3 / Webform 6.2.7 I want to create a conditional logic based on several fields and options. Something like:
Target field is invisible if field A = value 1 AND field B is one of value 1 or value 3.
I can't find a way to create a nested condition and my searches were pointing to the API but not to webform.
I've tried this way with a regex pattern:
invisible:
  ':input[name="civicrm_1_contact_1_cg2_custom_10"]':
    value:
      pattern: '^(Biologiste diplômé|Chercheur PhD|Médecin)$'
  ':input[name="civicrm_1_contact_1_cg2_custom_38"]':
    value: '2'

and different variations around this
invisible:
 -
   ':input[name="civicrm_1_contact_1_cg2_custom_10"]':
    value: '3'
    - or
   ':input[name="civicrm_1_contact_1_cg2_custom_10"]':
    value: '8'
-
  ':input[name="civicrm_1_contact_1_cg2_custom_38"]':
    value: '2'

but I can't succeed in both way. Did I miss something obvious or does it just doesn't work?
